# Set a file type to always use your Java program to open

Tags: java

I created a Java program to view text files. I have compiled it and created a Jar file also. Now I would like to right-click a .txt file and set it to always open with my program. I have tried this way but it doesn't work because the program is takes an argument (file name). Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: This is rather platform specific, but has been asked before. Try [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632793/use-a-java-application-as-the-default-program-for-a-particular-file-type) for Windows, for example.

Comment: Thank you. What key words did you use to search for similar topics?

Answer (score 0):

The arguments are passed into the main method - that's what the string array in the method header is for:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String firstArg = args[0];
    String secondArg = args[1];
    ...
}
```

Of course, you should always check for the length of the array before you try to access any of the elements, since it could be any length (including 0.)

On Windows at least, the name of the file that you want to open will be the first and only argument, so you can simply check if the array's length is 1, then if so pull out the first element as above.

Comment: Thanks for your response berry, but Quirliom redirected me to the right place.